# How to test data after await

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to add a test to test the following section of code, but I am not sure how, as the output says that lines `60-109` are uncovered. It looks something like this:

```
public async ngOnInit() {
  const data = await this.requestAppService.getData()
  this.tableModel =  { // Line 60
    ...this.tableModel,
    rows: data.map(
      /*
      * Map data
      */
    )
  }

  this.subscriptions.push(
    /* Add a subscription */
  )
  // Line 109
}
```

The test that I am using looks like this:

```
it('...', fakeAsync(() => {
  const spy = spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit').and.callThrough()
  component.ngOnInit()
  tick()
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
}))
```

This was just a guess of how I think I should test it, but it doesn't seem to cover the lines.
I have also tried `callFake`, which doesn't work either.

```
it('...', fakeAsync(() => {
  const spy = spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit').and.callFake(() => Promise.resolve())
  component.ngOnInit()
  tick()
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `spyOn` statement. You are spying on `ngOnInit` function. You must spy on the service's  `getData` function.

Inject & use `requestAppService` instance as shown below,

```
it('...', fakeAsync(() => {
  const spy = spyOn(requestAppService, 'getData').and.callThrough()
  component.ngOnInit()
  tick()
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
}))
```

**OR**

If you want `getData` to give you some mock `data` or `promise`,

```
it('...', fakeAsync(() => {
      const spy = spyOn(requestAppService, 'getData').and.callFake(() => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(YOUR_OBJECT);
      });
      component.ngOnInit()
      tick()
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
 }))
```

Comment: This still shows that lines `60-109` are uncovered.

Comment: you can write assertion like this `expect(component.tableModel.length ).toBe( data's length)`. if this passes then you can confirm that my solution is working. Then all you need to do is write the right asserts or expect statements.....

Comment: Yes you are right about `callThrough()`. I updated my answer...

Comment: `60-109` will automatically be covered if you write the right expect statements. But you had a basic problem of spying on `ngOninit` hook.  You can verify it by removing `60-109` lines and instead of that just write some basic code.That way you'll understand that `getData` actually gets you mock data & further lines get executed and covered.

Comment: That seems to have worked, now it has gotten to lines `88-109`

Comment: Glad it worked. I believe you have lots of callback in the function. You need to learn how to test callback functions or subscribe functions...